# EditText id cannot be accessed in main activity in kotlin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 fun CreateBirthdayCard(view: View) {
      val name = Input.editableText       
 }
```

Input is the id of EditText but it cannot be accessed in the main activity

Comment: show the full code

Comment: Please show your activity_main.xml

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences and the language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to access

```
val name: EditText = findViewById(R.id.input)
```